# Tag cut off when creating CV

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

When creating my CV today, I noticed that the `plasma` tag was cut off in the little hoverbox.  Here's a picture to show you what I mean:

[image: cut off hoverbox]

My current hypothesis is that the problem arises because the plasma tag has no associated description, but that's just a guess.

FWIW, I would expect it to work a little more like tagging in the "Ask a question" on the main site (e.g. the hoverbox appears right below the input field with the chips and the hoverbox has the same width as the input field):

[image: main site hoverbox]

If it matters ...

- My browser is Google Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit)
- My OS is OS-X version 10.11.2 MacbookPro laptop

Comment: I think this is probably a pretty minor problem because most people probably aren't trying to show-off their expertise is obscure tags ... But hey ... If you find a bug, why not report it?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to bring it to our attention. I'm having trouble reproducing this with the exact same OS/Browser as yourself. However this element of the UI is being worked on at present and might be subject to change.

Comment: @AndrewDunne -- I just checked again and it's still there for me.  I tried opening the inspector to get a look at what element is causing the problem, but any time I move around in the inspector, the tag box goes away so I'm having a tough time isolating it.